# creating a new tensor based on numpy indexes and the unique operator in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a new tensor containing the unique elements of another tensor and sorted according to an index tensor.

 Here is the illustrative code so far :

```
import tensorflow as tf
a, _ = tf.unique([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]])
b, _ = tf.unique([1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
d = a[b, :]
e = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(e)
  sess.run(d)
  print d
```

Basically, in this case, the desired output tensor should be equal to
[[3, 4], [1, 2]]

 Why my code isn't working as expected?

Comment: Here is the error that I have gotten : ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
 From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'strided_slice_1/stack_1' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?], [].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you encountered is due to the fact that tf.unique expects a 1-D input tensor (consult here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique)

If you run tf.unique on your 1-D b tensor, it works:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
a, _ = tf.unique([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]])
b, _ = tf.unique([1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
e = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(e)
  print (sess.run(b))
```

[1 0]

However, when you run tf.unique on your list of lists a, you will get an error:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
a, _ = tf.unique([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]])
b, _ = tf.unique([1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
e = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(e)
  print (sess.run(a))
```

InvalidArgumentError: unique expects a 1D vector.